# In Mongodb How to Give two different $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match

In Db I have some sample data:

**Object 1**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5934bb49b")
"payment" : {
"paid_total" : 500,
    "name" : "havi",
    "payment_mode" : "cash",
    "pd_no" : "PD20725001",
    "invoices" : [ 
        {
            "invoice_number" : "IN11803831583"
        }
    ],
"type" : "Payment"
}
```

**Object 2**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5934ee31e"),
"patient" : {
    "invoice_date" : "2018-07-26",
    "invoiceTotal" : 2000,
    "pd_no" : "PD20725001",
    "type" : "Invoice",
    "invoice_number" : "IN11803831583"
}
```

**Note**: All the Data is In same Collection

As the above shown data I have many objects in my database. How can I get the Sum from the data above of `invoiceTotal` and sum of `paid_total` and then subtract the `paid_total` from `invoiceTotal` and show the balance amount for matching `pd_no` and `invoice_number`.

The output I expect looks like

```
invoiceTotal : 2000
paid_total : 500
Balance : 1500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample Input :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b596969a88e07f00d6dac17"),
    "payment" : {
        "paid_total" : 500,
        "name" : "havi",
        "payment_mode" : "cash",
        "pd_no" : "PD20725001",
        "invoices" : [
                {
                        "invoice_number" : "IN11803831583"
                }
        ],
        "type" : "Payment"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b596986a88e07f00d6dac18"),
    "patient" : {
        "invoice_date" : "2018-07-26",
        "invoiceTotal" : 2000,
        "pd_no" : "PD20725001",
        "type" : "Invoice",
        "invoice_number" : "IN11803831583"
    }
}
```

Use this aggregate query :

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $project : {
    _id : 0,
     pd_no : { $ifNull: ["$payment.pd_no", "$patient.pd_no" ] },
     invoice_no : { $ifNull: [ { $arrayElemAt : ["$payment.invoices.invoice_number", 0] },"$patient.invoice_number" ] },
     type : { $ifNull: [ "$payment.type", "$patient.type" ] },
     paid_total : { $ifNull: [ "$payment.paid_total", 0 ] },
     invoice_total : { $ifNull: [ "$patient.invoiceTotal", 0 ] },
    }
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : {
            pd_no : "$pd_no",
            invoice_no : "$invoice_no"
        },
        paid_total : {$sum : "$paid_total"},
        invoice_total : {$sum : "$invoice_total"}
    }
},
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        pd_no : "$_id.pd_no",
        invoice_no : "$_id.invoice_no",
        invoice_total : "$invoice_total",
        paid_total : "$paid_total",
        balance : {$subtract : ["$invoice_total" , "$paid_total"]}
    }
}
])
```

In this query we are first finding the `pd_no` and `invoice_no`, which we are then using to group the documents. Next, we are getting the `invoice_total` and `paid_total` and then subtracting them to get the `balance`.

Output :

```
{
    "pd_no" : "PD20725001",
    "invoice_no" : "IN11803831583",
    "invoice_total" : 2000,
    "paid_total" : 500,
    "balance" : 1500
}
```

Comment: Thank you Subhashree Pradhan for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will only have documents with `invoiceTotal` or `paid_total` and never both at the same time.

you need first to get an amount to get the balance so if paid total it needs to be negative and positive on the case of the invoice total, and you can do this by using first the $project on the pipeline.

```
collection.aggregate([
{
    $project : {
        'patient.invoiceTotal': 1,
        'payment.paid_total': 1,
        ammount: { 
            $ifNull: ['$patient.invoiceTotal', { $multiply: [-1, '$payment.paid_total']}]
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: 'myGroup',
        invoiceTotal: { $sum: '$patient.invoiceTotal' },
        paid_total: { $sum: '$payment.paid_total' },
        balance: { $sum: '$ammount'  }
        }
}
])
```